# How to do Multiple Comparisons of Fitted mle2 Model Coefficients

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, multiple-comparisons, nonlinear-regression, ecology

Is there a way to do a multiple comparison test (similar to tukey HSD test) of coefficient estimates from a mle2 model in R?

Here is my specific application:

I have a large dataset containing observations of the woody plants used by browsing animals. The data set contains the species of each woody plant, the height of the plant, and number of "bites" (twig ends) on that plant available to browsing animals. Preliminary graphical analysis revealed that there is a complex non-linear relationship between the height of the plant and the number of bites. The relationship appears to be roughly similar to the shape of a gamma distribution. And the shape of the relationship appears to vary between species.

I successfully fit a modified "gamma" style function with a negative binomial distribution to the data using mle2() in R:

```
ml_nbinom <- mle2( allbites ~ dnbinom(mu = Bmax * Hmax^(-b*Hmax) * exp(b*Hmax) * Height^(b*Hmax) * exp(-b*Height), 
           size = overdisp ), data = model_bites,  
         parameters = list(b ~ Spp -1 , Hmax ~ Spp -1 , Bmax ~ Spp -1, overdisp ~ Spp -1 ), 
           start = list(b = 0.5, Hmax = 2.4, Bmax = 30, overdisp = 1.1),
           method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(b=0.001, Hmax = 0.001, Bmax = 0.001, overdisp = 0.001), control=list( maxit=4000, trace =3) )
```

Where the data are:

- Spp = Plant Species
- Height = Plant Height
- allbites = Available Plant Bites

And the fitted model coefficients are Hmax, Bmax, b, and overdisp.

Each coefficient was allowed to vary with species. So, for example, I end up with 21 estimates of Bmax (one for each species). And so for Hmax, etc.

I would like to run a post-hoc multiple comparison test on the Bmax estimates of each species. (That is, I want to see if any species have Bmax coefficients significantly different from other species).

If this were a glm model fit, I could run a Tukey HSD test. For example, something like:

```
summary(glht(ml_nbinom, linfct = mcp(Bmax = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("fdr") )
```

However, glht doesn't work with mle2 models.

Is there something similar I can do for a mle2 model?